# When to disconnect MutationObserver in Chrome / Web Extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

I want to know when or if I need to disconnect a `MutationObserver` in my content script to avoid memory leaks.

So my content script checks all new additions to the `DOM` and updates the HTML accordingly. I use a `MutationObserver` for this which is created and started at in the content script.

My question is, does the `MutationObserver` destroy itself when a new page is loaded or must I listen to page changes to disconnect it and destroy it myself each time.

Here is the relevant code:

```js
function startObserver(textSize: number, lineHeight: number, font: string = "Droid Arabic Naskh") {

    let config: MutationObserverInit = {
        attributes: false,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true,
        characterDataOldValue: false,
    };

    let callback: MutationCallback = (mutationsList: MutationRecord[]) => {
        mutationsList.forEach((record: MutationRecord) => {
            // If something has been added
            if (record.addedNodes.length > 0) {

                //  For each added node
                record.addedNodes.forEach((addedNode: Node) => {

                    // For each node with Arabic script in addedNode
                    getArabicTextNodesIn(addedNode).forEach((arabicNode: Node) => {

                        // Update arabicNode only if it hasn't been updated
                        if (arabicNode.parentElement && arabicNode.parentElement.getAttribute("class") != "ar") {
                            updateNode(arabicNode, textSize, lineHeight, font);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    };

    if (!observer) {
        observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        observer.observe(document.body, config);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/482

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh My case fits into approach 2, I observe the entire document body for changes, a single observer for all changes. I understand the issues of this in front end development, however, I don't know about it in the context of Web Extensions. Will the browser recreate the document and so the observer automatically disconnects when the user browses to another page? Is my null check at the bottom enough? Testing this has shown me that it's safe and does disconnect but I'm not fully sure. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Content scripts are part of the page execution environment, not some trans-dimensional alternative space. Reloading the page destroys all running content scripts and their objects.

Comment: Very good and thorough question, btw! Contains all necessary details and is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out a long time ago thanks to [@xOxxm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) and some personal testing and playing around but answering myself in case someone else needs this in the future

> Does the `MutationObserver` destroy itself when a new page is loaded or must I listen to page changes to disconnect it and destroy it myself each time?

Yes the `MutationObserver` destroys itself upon leaving the page (the `document` has changed) so the above code was in fact safe and devoid of any possible memory leaks.